# How to find a block in a file and insert a string at particular location using awk/sed commands

Tags: shell

My requirement is to read a file and find a string in a block[] and insert a new string followed by above searched string.

For example, data in the input file looks like

```
#starting of the file
[MAIN]    
.   
.   
.   
connection = TCPIP   
connection = HTTP   
connection = HTTPS   
.   
.   
.   

[TCPIP]   
name =  tcpip1   
port = 2222   
.   
.   
.   

[HTTP]   
name = http1   
port = 3333   
.    
.   
.

[HTTPS]   
name = https1   
port = 4444   
.   
.   
.   
#end of the file
```

My requirement is
1)I need to insert a new connection(MQ) in the [MAIN] block after a last occurrence of the connection
2) I need to insert a block at the end of the file with [MQ] and insert all required details

Expected output should be

```
#starting of the file   
[MAIN]   
.   
.   
.   
connection = TCPIP   
connection = HTTP   
connection = HTTPS   
connection = MQ   
.   
.   
.   

[TCPIP]   
name =  tcpip1   
port = 2222   
.   
.   
.   

[HTTP]   
name = http1   
port = 3333   
.    
.   
.   
[HTTPS]   
name = https1   
port = 4444   
.   
.   
.   
[MQ]   
name = mq1   
port = 5555   
.   
.   
.   
#end of the file
```

I have tried to used awk and sed commands to find occurrence of a string and insert a new string. but, I didn't find how to get a last occurrence of a string [connection].
Could you please let me know how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this.  Here is one way (with sample output):

```
$ awk '/\[MAIN\]/ {n=1;print;next} n==1 && /\[/ {n=0;print "CONNECTION=MQ\n"} {print} END {print "[MQ]\nname=mq1"}' input 
[MAIN]    
.   
.   
.   
connection = TCPIP   
connection = HTTP   
connection = HTTPS   
.   
.   
.   

CONNECTION=MQ

[TCPIP]   
name =  tcpip1   
port = 2222   
.   
.   
.   

[HTTP]   
name = http1   
port = 3333   
.    
.   
.

[HTTPS]   
name = https1   
port = 4444   
.   
[MQ]
name=mq1
```

Lets look at each `awk` statement in turn:

- `/\[MAIN\]/ {n=1;print;next}`

  This checks for the start of the MAIN block.  If it starts, it sets the flag `n` to one, prints the line to output, and then jumps to start the next line.
- `n==1 && /\[/ {n=0;print "CONNECTION=MQ\n"}`

  This statement is executed at the beginning of the first block after MAIN.  It prints the line `CONNECTION=MQ` before the start of the next block.  It also resets the flag `n` to zero so that we know that we have left the MAIN block
- `{print}`

  This just echoes input lines to standard output.
- `END {print "[MQ]\nname=mq1"}`

  At the end of the file, this prints out the new block that you want.

#### How to modify in place

`awk` does not directly support modifying the source file in place.   The same effect, however, is easy to achieve:

```
mv -f input input.bak && awk '/^\[MAIN\]/ {n=1;print;next} n==1 && /^\[/ {n=0;print "CONNECTION=MQ\n"} {print} END {print "[MQ]\nname=mq1"}' input.bak >input
```

The above creates a backup copy of the original file and then overwrites the original file with the modified version.

Comment: How can I have these changes applied on my input file instead of having them in the standard output. How can I do it?

Comment: @user3790141 See the last section of the updated answer.